# How to use the same facebook application for different websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a small CMS in PHP and we're putting on social integration.

The content is changed by a single administrator who as right for publishing news, events and so on...

I'd to add this feature, when the admin publishes something it's already posted on facebook wall. I'm not very familiar with facebook php SDK, and i'm a little bit confused about it.

If (make it an example) 10 different sites are using my CMS, do I have to create 10 different facebook application? (let's assume the 10 websites are all in different domains and servers)

2nd, is there a way for authenticating with just PHP (something like sending username&password directly) so that the user does not need to be logged on facebook?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read up on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/.

Its really easy and straight forward and well explained.

Your question is so vague and extensive that it cannot be answered well here.

If you experience any specific implementation problems, this is the right place.

However to answer atleast a part of your question:

The most powerful tool when working with facebook applications is the Graph API.

Its principle is very simple. You can do almonst any action on behalf of any user or application. You have to generate a token first that identifies the user and the proper permissions. Those tokens can be made "permanent" so you can do background tasks. Usually they are only active a very short time so you can perform actions while interacting with the user. The process of generating tokens involves the user so that he/she has to confirm the privileges you are asking for.

For websites that publish something automatically you would probably generate a permanent token one time that is active as long as you remove the app in your privacy settings.

Basically yuo can work with any application on any website. There is no limitation. However there are two ways of generating tokens. One involves on an additional request and one is done client side, which is bound to one domain oyu specifiedin your apps settings.

Addendum:

@ArtoAle

you are right about every app beeing assighend to exactly one domain. however once you obtained a valid token it doesnt matter from where or who you use it within the graph api.

let me expalin this a little bit:

it would make no sense since it is you doing the request. there is no such thing as "where the request is coming from". of course there is the "referer" header information, but it can be freely specified and is not used in any context of this.

the domain you enter in your apps settings only restricts where facebook redirects the user to.

why?

this ensures that some bad guy cannot set up a website on any domain and let the user authorize an app and get an access token with YOUR application.

so this setting ensures that the user and the access token are redirected back to YOUR site and not to another bad site.

but there is an alternative. if you use the control flow for desktop applications you don't get an access token right after the user has been redirected back. you get a temporary SESSION-TOKEN that you can EXCCHANGE for an access token. this exchange is done server side over the REST api and requires your application secret. So at this point it is ensured that it is YOU who gets the token.

This method can be done on any domain or in case of desktop applications on no domain at all.

This is a quote from the faceboo docs:

> To convert sessions, send a POST
>   request to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/exchange_sessions
>   with a comma-separated list of
>   sessions you want to convert:
>
> curl client_id=your_app_id \
>        -F client_secret=your_app_secret \
>        -F sessions=2.DbavCpzL6Yc_XGEI0Ip9GA__.3600.1271649600-12345,2.aBdC...
>   \
>        https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/exchange_sessions
>   The response from the request is a
>   JSON array of OAuth access tokens in
>   the same order as the sessions given:
>
> [   {
>       "access_token": "...",
>       "expires": 1271649600,   },   ... ]

However you don't need this method as its a bit more complex. For your use case i would suggest using a central point of authorization.

So you would specify your ONE domain as a redirect url. This domain is than SHARED between your websites. there you can obtain the fully valid access token and seamlessly redirect the user back to your specific project website and pass along the access token.

This way you can use the traditional easy authentication flow that is probably also more future proof.

The fact remains. Once the access token is generated you can perform any action from any domain, there is no difference as ther is literally no "domain" where the request is coming from (see above).

apart from that, if you want some nice javascript features to work - like the comments box or like button, you need to setup up [open graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) correctly.

if you have some implementation problems or as you said "domain errors" please describe them more clearly, include the steps you made and if possible an error message.

Comment: ok. I should have mentioned about graph api in my answer. I assumed its implicitly understood. My mistake.

Comment: "Basically yuo can work with any application on any website"..Correct me if I'm wrong, I can use the same fb-application on any websites, as long as I hava a valid auth token?

Comment: @ArtOle thats correct. only the javascript authentication flow is bound to a domain. but you can use desktop authentication flow alternatively, it works also over web but involves an additional server side request.

Comment: some application featuers are only enabled if you add the og: tags with the application id to your website, but you can do that on several websites. there are no domain boundaries.

Comment: @ArtoAle: Not really, the applications is assigned to **ONE** domain, if your "websites" are sub-domains then yeah, otherwise you need different apps

Comment: @JoeHopgartner: Sorry didn't refresh the page for like 1 hour, are you sure about what you are saying?! we've had domain error because of this

Comment: i am sure abuot what i am saying but perhaps i didnt express myself clear enough. i added a more detailed explanation to my answer.

Comment: Ok, i finally decided to implement my websites this way. When setting up the website I use a webservice hosted in mywebsite (connected to the fb app) to retrive a permanent access token, which I store in a db. (local to each websites), and I use the token for any fb call I need :)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to break up your question in to smaller understandable units. Its very difficult to understand what you are driving at.

My understanding of your problem could be minimal, but here goes...

1_ No you do not create 10 different facebook application. Create a single facebook application and make it a service entry point. So that all your cms sites could talk to this one site to interact with facebook. ( A REST service layer).

2_ Facebook api does not support username and password authentication. They only support oauth2.0. Although Oauth is not trivial, but since they have provided library for that, implementing authentication is pretty trivial.

Comment: yeah, it's definetly messy, sry for that. Actually I really have to spend more time in reading fb API docs =)